V2 word order in "egal wie" Kalauer
In a Kalauer like

Egal wie dicht du bist, Goethe war Dichter.

The presentation has a subordinate clause preceding the main clause. Shouldn't that move the verb to before the subject to maintain V2 ordering? I would expect the construction to be

Egal wie dicht du bist, war Goethe Dichter.

Is "egal wie" grammatically different from "weil"? Or is it more like a set-phrase and is just "one of those things"?

First off: this is a pun. "Dichter" is a "poet" (from the verb "dichten", to write poetry here), but "dichter" (notice the capitalisation) is the comparative of "dicht" (tight, sealed). Also notice that there is a second meaning to the verb "dichten", which is "make tight", "to seal".
Furthermore there is a meaning of "dicht", which you are unlikely to find in a dictionary: it is a colloquial expression for "drunken", therefore (again, notice the capitalisation): "Goethe war Dichter" means *Goethe was a poet", but "Goethe war dichter" could be interpreted as Goethe was more drunk.
There is the so-called Feldermodell to analyze german sentence structure. But this is not even relevant here, I just mention it for further reading on that topic.

Is "egal wie" grammatically different from "weil"?

Yes, it is. "Weil" introduces a Kausalsatz, a special form of a "Relativsatz". The "Egal wie dicht du bist" is, in the strictest sense, an ellipsis (an omission of parts, although a commonly used one in colloquial speech) and the full sentence would be:

Es ist egal, wie dicht du bist

This makes it obvious that it is a main sentence in its own right (accompanied by a relative sentence on its own) and the two sentences are just coupled by a comma. The complete structure is:

(main s. + relative s.), (main s.).


I feel the need to defend that I understood (and heartily approve of) the pun... just that the elision made it seem like V2 was violated.

Just to make sure that non-native speakers get the pun completely: "dicht" also means "drunk" so Goethe was completely stoned.

There is a comma missing in Es ist egal[,] wie dicht du bist which makes the ellipsis hypothesis dubious IMHO.

@RHa: the "ellipsis hypothesis" is not dubious, but correct, although it could need some explanation: the "Es ist egal" is a main sentence in its own right, "wie es ist" is a relative sentence, specificying further the attribute "egal" - it doesn't matter (main sentence) in which way it is (relative sentence).

@Jens: thank you, I added some explanation.

This is basically two complete sentences. The usual writeup would use a colon
"Egal wie dicht du bist: Goethe war Dichter" or a hyphen: "Egal wie dicht du bist - Goethe war Dichter"

Regarding "usual writeup", everywhere I've seen it before has always presented it as I showed, with the only punctuation being one comma between bist and Goethe and a period at the end.  For example, https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalauer#Beispiele (as of the 2024-Jul-24 edit, which is the most recent as of this comment)

First off,

Egal, wie dicht du bist, war Goethe dichter.

is perfectly possible. There are other instances where this kind of variation occurs. The meaning expressed by egal, wie dicht du bist is equivalent to that of a type of subordinate clause called Irrelevanzkonditional.

Selbst wenn du stockbesoffen bist, war Goethe dichter.
Wie besoffen du auch bist, Goethe war dichter.
Magst du auch noch so besoffen sein, Goethe war dichter.

As the examples show, these type of subordinate clause can in theory appear both in the Vorfeld or to its left, in the Vorvorfeld or linkes Außenfeld; for the terminology, see Das topologische Satzmodell (Feldermodell).
Some other examples can be found here: Wortfolge: "Selbst wenn die Dreharbeiten schwierig waren, der Film ist ein großer Erfolg."
The first encounter with clauses in the Vorvorfeld are free relatives and conditionals with a resumptive element (der or dann, respectively).

Wer so fährt, dem sollte man den Führerschein entziehen.
Wenn du Zeit hast, dann komme ich nachher vorbei.

